# click on all elements by id or by class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to click on all 'my_id_' id's starting with the last, so i created this code in jQuery. Everything works fine, but every time i must reload the page, to "find" the next id. Is there a way to do this without reloading the page?

```
 <div class = "completed" >
     <a id="my_id_1" class="my_class_name" title="Click here"></a>
 </div>                                                          

 <div class = "completed" >                                      
     <a id="my_id_2" class="my_class_name" title="Click here"></a>
 </div>                                                          

 <div class = "completed" >                                      
     <a id="my_id_3" class="my_class_name" title="Click here"></a>
 </div>                                                          

 <div class = "completed" >                                      
     <a id="my_id_4" class="my_class_name" title="Click here"></a>
 </div>                                                          

 <div class = "completed" >                                      
     <a id="my_id_5" class="my_class_name" title="Click here"></a>
 </div>
```

my code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var id = "#" + $('[id ^= "my_id_"]').last().prop("id");
    if (id != "#undefined") {
        $(id)[0].click();
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 500);
    }
}, 2000);
```

also tried by class, but no luck...

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".my_class_name").length) {
        $(".my_class_name:last").trigger("click");
    }
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 500);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: for the love of god don't format your HTML like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Why do you think you even need the timeout?

Comment: Why you need reload??

Comment: @DLeh sorry about that :(

Comment: @Stephan Muller there are few buttons on the page, i need to click on all of them one by one, and when i do that button dissapears. The timeout is needed because when i click another confirmation appears, so need to click there too, but you are right, in this example is quite unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the reverse function on the array of selected items before triggering the click event on each one.

```
var reversed = $(".my_class_name").get().reverse();

$(reversed).each(function () {
    $(this).trigger("click");
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0h54vav2/